# Airflow task run on all nodes

Tags: airflow

I have airflow cluster using celery and redis. I have one task that i want to run on all workers. How can I do that ?

Reason: We are adding and reducing airflow worker depending upon worker load. I have to have one task run on all nodes.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I am actually look to implement something similar.. Did you find anything @kppatel?

Comment: no, I am still using cron

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: for our purpose, we use cron.  It is running for the last 3 years without any issues. But our background task has a much smaller footprint. 

if you have a fix number of named workers, then you can create an airflow task to run each airflow worker.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to monitor your worker nodes in an Airflow cluster, increasing worker nodes/executor if worker under high load? Is this what you're trying to do?

If so, I think this kind of job should be managed by other tool, like Jenkins + Ansible.

If not, ignore this or update your question with more information.

Comment: I am not trying to monitor airflow worker, Airflow does allow us to monitor nodes. However, I am not able to run certain task in all nodes. For example VPN connection can be broke after some time, we want to run sh file that reconnect to VPN, but I want to do it in all nodes, not one random node.

Comment: I don't think airflow is designed to solve that kind of task you mentioned. I think you know the task is executed by an executor in worker node, so what you're trying to do is distributing a task to exact one executor of every worker, which is not the way airflow works. Try Cron or Jenkins+Ansible might be easier to achieve that.

Comment: I agree with you if it was normal stuff. But I need to run this for airflow support. Otherwise, my airflow just start failing task. I am currently using cron.  However, I was wondering if there was better solution than just basic cron job